# How does SwiftUI run layout on Views?

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUI Views only implement the `View` trait, which only consists of `body` and an associated type.

How does SwiftUI now run layout computation on the View?

Given a simple example.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Somehow SwiftUI must run functions to calculate the size of `ContentView` (or any other View), without me explicitly implementing such functions for that View.

I have not found any documentation on that part in Apples documentation.

Also, as `Text` is also only a View, how does it calculate the layout container for the text?

Comment: Check out https://talk.objc.io/. They have a whole bunch of videos on that subject.

Comment: Some views like Text use the less space possible, some other use the most get can. By default views like Text are centered.

Comment: I'm not asking how they calculate their space, i ask how the SwiftUI runtime is starting the calculation process, if there is no `get_layout` method on the `View` protocol and non is required for custom views.

Comment: Thanks @koen, i forget that default implementations are possible in Swift for Protocols.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267

"You can use protocol extensions to provide a default implementation to any method or property requirement of that protocol. If a conforming type provides its own implementation of a required method or property, that implementation will be used instead of the one provided by the extension."

Comment: The video, which describes how the `View` Protocol is extended is the following: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E225-view-protocols-and-shapes?t=89